# how to fix Javascript function arguments (when i use a variable to pass the argument)

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

```
<p id="demo">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2">Click me.</p>
<script>
x="demo";
b="ttt";
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction(x,b)};
x="demo2";
b="555"
document.getElementById("demo2").onclick = function() {myFunction(x,b)};
function myFunction(x,b) {
  document.getElementById(x).innerHTML =b ;
}
```

My intent is for demo,  use onclick function with x="demo" b="ttt"; and for demo 2, use onclick function with x="demo2" and b="555". but seems both functions used most updated x and b values.

Answer (score 1):

## You're re-assigning `x` variable.

- The best approach is close your logic with functions, so you can create two functions called `demo` and `demo2`.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
let demo = function(x,b) {
  document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
    myFunction(x, b)
  };
};

let x = "demo";
let b = "ttt";
demo(x, b);

let demo2 = function(x,b) {
  document.getElementById("demo2").onclick = function() {
    myFunction(x, b)
  };
};

x = "demo2";
b = "555"
demo2(x, b);

function myFunction(x, b) {
  document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = b;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2">Click me.</p>
```

See? now your logic is working!

Comment: Thanks. But if there are hundreds of x and b... is creating hundreds of onclick function the only option?  I was thinking to do that using a loop and use one function and pass x,b through that function's argument.but seems that function always uses the most updated value of x/b (not the x/b value when document.getelement("demo").onclick=funcion happens).

Answer (score 0):

or another way to think about it is like this... but yeah, you probably want to do what Ele did ^

```html
<html>

  <button id="demo">Click me.</button>
  <button id="demo2">Click me.</button>
  
  <script>
    var x = "demo";
    var b = "ttt";
    document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener(
      "click", () => myFunction(x, b)
    );

    function diffScope() {
      var x = "demo2";
      var b = "555"
      document.getElementById("demo2").addEventListener(
        "click", () => myFunction(x, b)
      );
    }
    
    function myFunction(x, b) {
      document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = b
    };
    
    // Note: you're initializing that inner function called diffScope
    // from above AFTER the first "demo" has already been assigned 
    // the eventListener

    diffScope();

  </script>
</html>
```